# Combine conditional styles and hover in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, webstorm, jsx

I have the problem that I want to implement a conditional style and a hover function (for TableRows). Individually both work perfectly fine but together the hover function does not work.

**CSS**

```
const StyledTableRow = withStyles((theme) => ({
root: {
    tableRow: {
        "&$hover:hover": {
            backgroundColor: "blue"
        }
    },
},
}))(TableRow);
```

**JSX**

```
<TableBody>
                {RankingData.map((row) => (
<StyledTableRow hover
                                    className={classes.tableRow}
                                    key={row.name}
                                    style ={(
                                        row.remaining === "2" ||
                                        row.remaining === "1" )
                                        ? { background : " #ffff66" }:{ background : " 
#ff9999" }}>
                        <StyledTableCell align="right" size= 'small'>{row.starters} 
</StyledTableCell>
                        <StyledTableCell align="right" size= 'small'>{row.remaining} 
</StyledTableCell>
                    </StyledTableRow>
                ))}
            </TableBody>
```

Does anyone know what I have to do to that the conditional formatting and the hovering will work together?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be the fact that you use `background` in `style` but `backgroundColor` in `hover`? Try to use only `backgroundColor` or `background`

**EDIT**

I think I figured it out

[Material UI docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#shorthand)

As I understand from the docs the syntax which you are using to style is used to override existing classes on components.

And according to the docs on TableRow [here](https://material-ui.com/ru/api/table-row/#css), the class `tableRow` does not exist. That is why if you change styles in it nothing changes.

So here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-pl6sb

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried that but unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: And if
```tableRow: {
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#000000!important"
    }
  }```

?

Comment: !important also doesn't seem to help. What I also noticed: no matter which background color I set in the StyledTableRow constant, the hover color doesn't change. Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: Yes, how to you get ```classes```? Does your class even reaches the element?

Comment: From my understanding, I get it through className={classes.root} . It works fine when I don't have the conditional formatting (can't change the color though) but when I add it it doesn't work for the formatted styles.

Comment: if you change the background color of ```tableRow``` not on hover, but default background color - does this affect your UI?

Comment: Thank you! That seems to be the problem. It does not affect my UI. Do you know what I am doing wrong that the class doesn't reach the element?

Comment: The hover in the <StyledTableRow hover> is responsible that the hovering works I think. But the tableRow is not reached.

Comment: Thank you so much, Allen! That was the problem. Thank you for your time and have a great day!